# How to delete a file with a weird name?

Tags: linux, posix

I wrote a program that uses POSIX memory-mapping function (`mmap`)

The program takes a file (`a.dat`) and memory-maps it for reading/writing.

Due to errors in the program, every time I run the program a file with some weird names (e.g., `?d?P?^z??d?P?^z?`) is
created. The error is resolved but I am not able to delete the files.

I am not able to delete it either using command line or by select/deleting from window manager.

So how should I delete it? I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Even if you cannot easily type the filename, deleting it from a graphical file manager should work fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Aditya, I have no problem deleting such files from the command line when escaping their names with single quotes (`rm '?d?P?^z??d?P?^z?'`). Did you try that?

Comment: deleting from graphical window manager just says cannot delete file 'filename'. @Frédéric Hamidi Thanks for helping me delete one file. But the other one with name '?m?P???)?m?P???)' isnt getting deleted ... The error message says "rm: cannot remove `?m?P???)?m?P???)': No such file or directory"

Comment: @Aditya, that other file must have non-printable characters in its name. Try the following steps: 1/ Move all the valid files out of that folder, 2/ Issue `rm *` inside the folder.

Comment: When typing the file name try to start with quotes, then use auto completion as soon as it works (after one or two characters). Auto completion would be hitting the [tab] key to make the shell auto complete the name. This way you might be more successful to correctly escape the names.

Comment: Auto completion failed while deleting the first file itself. I think the best option would be to take a backup and delete all those 'weird' files

Comment: If there are enough printable characters, you can specify a wildcard which matches only the problematic file. `rm *m*P*m*P*` Similarly, if you know the length of the file name, you can at least limit the scope of the wildcard; frequently, problematic file names are either very short or very long.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`rm -i -- *` will prompt you to delete each file.  You can and should change '*' to a narrower match if there are a lot of files. The `--` stops processing options, so a file named `-d` will be removed by `rm` successfully.

I've used that in the past and it works until you hit a special character or 2 that it does not like.

Comment: This doesn't work for a file named -d for example.

Comment: @SCO If it doesn't work for you and depending on your version of `rm`, you can do `rm -i -- *`  The `--` tells some versions of rm there are no more command line line switches after the `--` and to treat further args as filenames.

Comment: I think this answer should include the comment suggested by @JimR : Using `--` in the `rm` command.

Answer (score 25):

you can use `ls -li` to show all files by their inode. Then run this command to remove the file:

```
find . -inum ${INODE_NUM} -delete
```

I added `-maxdepth 1` to my find just to be safe:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -inum ${INODE_NUM} -delete
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `ls -i` is good enough.

Comment: `ls` doesn't delete files. OP wants this.

Comment: The first line of your answer says, “you can use `ls -li` to show all files by their inode.”  I’m pointing out that `ls -i` is good enough to get a list of filenames and their corresponding inode numbers.  (But of course you need `ls -ia` if you want to include dot-files.)

Comment: It is better to simply pass the `-delete`option to `find`, in order to minimize the usage of the wrong filename.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a basic find/confirm files by pattern and rm work?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*P*d*P*z" -exec ls -a {} \; 
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*P*d*P*z" -exec rm {} \;
```